# How to make an html element have the same starting width as a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am working on a simple web page and I have a pretty simple problem (possible CSS question). On the webpage, I have a table and a button right under it. I want to make the button have the same "starting width?" as the table. I included the link to the screenshot so you could get a better understanding of what I am trying to do. 
[image: Link to the screenshot]

```html
<table id="myTable" align="center" border="1px" style="width: 1400px; line-height: 30px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="18" style="font-family: Verdana;">
        <h2>Данные договоров</h2>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <t class="element">
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">ID</th>
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Продукт</th>
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Пакет</th>
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Основной договор</th>
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Номер договора</th>
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Страхователь</th>
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Премия в валюте</th>
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Комиссия в валюте</th>
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Дата договора</th>
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Дата начала договора</th>
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Дата окончания договора</th>
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Дата окончания страх. защиты</th>
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Время расторажения</th>
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Причина расторажения</th>
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Статус договора</th>
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Номер заявления</th>
      <th class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Вложения</th>
    </t>
    <tr id="searchRes">
      <!-- querie results are put here -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Please consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for us.

Comment: From the screenshot it is not clear what you want to do with the button. Do you want it to be the same width as the first column of the table? Do you want it to be placed under table but be right under first column? Something else?

Comment: You have `style="width: 1400px;` already for the table, why not do the same for the button?

Comment: Do you mean you want the left side of the button to line up with the left side of the table?  Or that you want the button to be the same overall width of the table? (or both?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you were trying to achieve? [Codepen snippet](https://codepen.io/jphawk/pen/MWKbXWg)

I made the table smaller to make it more representative, but basically the idea is the same. Wrap the table and the button into one parent `<div>` and center it with giving the parent `<div>` the same width as your table has and apply `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: Or if he wants the button to be as wide as the entire table, add this to the CSS: `button { width: 100%;}`

Comment: Thank you for the help, that is exactly what I wanted!